# How to add a measure at the end of the matrix, which performs certain calculations in Power BI?

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, visualization, powerquery

The output matrix in Power BI should contain the measures X, Y, and Z. Where

1. X = (B+C);
   `X = IF((MAX(Sheet1[C1])) = "B" , SUM(Sheet1[C2]), IF(MAX(Sheet1[C1]) = "C", SUM(Sheet1[C2])))`
2. Y = A - (B+c);
   `Y = IF(MAX(Sheet1[C1]) = "A", CALCULATE( ((-1) * SUM(Sheet1[C2])) + [X]))`
3. Z = (A/(A-(B+c)))*100%

I have achieved till total which is quite easy but, I am unable to replicate the same output in Power BI.

Thanks.

[image: Sample Picture]

Comment: What is the issue that you are facing?

Comment: The matrix visual doesn't support this type of adding items to the totals. You'll have to add another table with the values in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried and found a way to achieve the above result with a couple of slicers and more tables, sadly I have only succeeded to achieve till `Y = A-(B+C)`.

SO the whole visualisation till `Y` will be a combination of tables and matrices. To achieve the desired visual, I followed the following steps:

1. Start by creating a matrix with columns `C1` and `C2` in the row section of the matrix and the `C2` in the Value section of the matrix and set it to the sum of 'C2`.

[image: Matrix output]

2. Create a measure X with the following formula:

   ```
    X = IF(((MAX(Sheet1[C1])) = "B" || (MAX(Sheet1[C1]) = "C")) , SUM(Sheet1[C2]))
   ```

Create a table with the column `C1` and measure `X` in it.

3. Create a slicer with `C1`, open the *Format* pane go to `Edit Interaction` options, and set the interaction to only the Table having measure `X` and the column `C1`, disable any other interaction.
4. In the slicer select the option `B` and `C`, because the X is only concerned with the values B & C. The table should display the total.

[image: Table X]

5. Create another measure Y with the following DAX:

   ```
    Y = CALCULATE(SUM(Sheet1[C2]), KEEPFILTERS(Sheet1[C1] = "A")) + CALCULATE(-SUM(Sheet1[C2]), KEEPFILTERS(Sheet1[C1] IN {"B", "C"}))
   ```
6. Repeat the steps 3 & 4 again for measure Y. This should be your output.

[image: Y output]

7. Now hide all the extra slicers from the Selection option in the Format pane in the ribbon and properly format all the tables and set the layer order as follows:

[image: Slicers]

8. This should be the final output.

[image: Final Output]